# Permanently save SQL database created using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, sql.js

I have created a SQL database using Javascript using the below function.

```
function myFunction()
{
var db = new SQL.Database();
db.run("CREATE TABLE test (col1, col2);");
db.run("INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?), (?,?)", [1,111,2,222]);

var stmt = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 BETWEEN $start AND $end");
stmt.getAsObject({$start:1, $end:1}); // {col1:1, col2:111}

stmt.bind({$start:1, $end:2});
while(stmt.step()) { 
    var row = stmt.getAsObject();
   }
}
```

When I execute the function, it works perfectly. After commenting the 4th and 5th lines I expect to retrieve the values which I previously stored in the created database. But it creates a new database every time. Kind of a temporary database. How to fetch the previously inserted values, without creating the DB each and every time.

Note : Import

```
<script src='sql.js'></script>
```

[Download SQL.js](https://kripken.github.io/sql.js/js/sql.js)

```
 document.getElementById("text1").value = row.col1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated at https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/,

> It uses a virtual database file stored in memory, and thus does’nt
>   persist the changes made to the database. However, it allows you to import any existing sqlite file, and to export the created database as a javascript typed array.